# Sentence rephrasing issues

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, parallelism

This is a question from sentence correction.

> **Incorrect**: The possibility of an attack on Indian Point, a nuclear power plant, has caused local governmental oﬃcials to plan evacuation routes, build shelters, and ***offering*** citizens potassium pills ***so there will be*** fewer casualties in case of a leak.

.

> **Correct**: The possibility of an attack on Indian Point, a nuclear power plant, has caused local governmental oﬃcials to plan evacuation routes, build shelters, and ***offer*** citizens potassium pills ***in order to have*** fewer casualties in case of a leak.

The word "**offering**" is changed to "**offer**" in order to make the sentence parallel.

But I don't understand the reason of changing the phrase from "**so there will be**" to "**in order to have**". Can anyone explain me the reason? If I retain the first as it is, will the meaning remain the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that this sentence is in **perfect tense**.  However, "*so there will be*" **is future tense**.  Therefore, *planing evacuation routes* takes place **before** the sentence is said, while "*fewer casualties*" exist **afterward**.

However, you may not want that **implication**; maybe the leak has **already happened**.  Therefore, it is better to use "*in order to have*" because that doesn't **specify the tense**.

Also, **stylistically**, "*in order to have*" sounds better; it is generally a **stylistic rule** that **full infinitives** ("*to [verb]*") sound better than **gerunds** ("*[verb]ing*") in cases in which both can be used.

Comment: May I know what is "stylistic rule"?